# How to wait for a promise to be resolved from a page object which is returning another page object?

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

My pageObject file:

```
 this.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation = function (item) {  
    this.innerMenu = this.companyInformation.all(by.className('innermenu')).first();     
    this.selectedItem = this.innerMenu.all(by.tagName('li')).filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '') === item.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '');
        });
    });
    this.selectedItem.click();
    this.selectedItem.getText().then(function (text) {
        var option = text.toString(); 
        var pageObject = option.replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase(); 
 *******return require('./' + pageObject + '.page.js');**********
    })
};
```

this is a line from my spec file:

```
var generalInfo = pageObject.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation('generalInformation');
```

as you can see, the call to `pageObject.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation('generalInformation')` returns another pageobject.

When i try to access my generalInfo variable in my specs, it throws error

> generalInfo is undefined

.what can i do access my returned pageobject via generalInfo variable.

If i put my `return require('./anotherPageObject.js')` outside the getText().then, it works fine.But i have to do some operations on the text to modify my naming convention, so that it returns the proper page object file. (i want to return a pageobject file named as 'general_information.page.js')

Comment: Please contact your local techsupport: Your keyboard apparently engages capslock when typing titles...

Comment: @MarcB paging convertcase.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `this.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation` doesn't return anything. Add a `return` statement to return the last promise:

```js
this.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation = function (item) {  
    this.innerMenu = this.companyInformation.all(by.className('innermenu')).first();     
    this.selectedItem = this.innerMenu.all(by.tagName('li')).filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '') === item.toUpperCase().replace(/ |-/g, '');
        });
    });
    this.selectedItem.click();
    return this.selectedItem.getText().then(function (text) {
        var option = text.toString(); 
        var pageObject = option.replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase(); 
        return require('./' + pageObject + '.page.js');
    });
};
```

```js
pageObject.clickTheProvidedValueInCompanyInformation('generalInformation').then(function(page){
  console.log(page);
});
```